# Pipe foreach loop with Export-Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

The script below is meant to read a list of servers in `$ServerName` and a list of files in `$Myfiles` then export the `Select-Object` criteria to Excel using the [`ImportExcel`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/) module. The problem I am having is the script loops through the 2 files and only outputs the criteria for the last server and file from the 2 lists.

If I change `Export-Excel` to `Export-Csv C:\outputFile.csv -Append` the script works as intended and loops through each file on each server and exports all the data. This would be fine but I prefer to use `Export-Excel`, so I can use Pivot Tables and coloring in my reports.

```
foreach ($server in Get-Content "C:\MyServers.txt") {
    $ServerName = $server
    foreach ($file in Get-Content "C:\MyFiles.txt") {
        $Myfiles = $file
        Get-ChildItem -Path \\$server\$Myfiles -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            ForEach-Object {
                try {
                    $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty ServerName $ServerName
                } catch {}
                $_
            } |
            Select-Object ServerName, Name, LastWriteTime, Directory |
            Export-Excel -Path C:\outputFile.xlsx
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the entire output to a variable, and then pipe that to `Export-Excel` at the end:

```
$data = foreach ($ServerName in Get-Content "C:\MyServers.txt")
{
    foreach ($Myfiles in Get-Content "C:\MyFiles.txt")
    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path \\$ServerName\$Myfiles -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |ForEach-Object {
            try {
                $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty ServerName $ServerName
            } catch {}
            $_
        } | Select-Object ServerName,Name,LastWriteTime,Directory
    }
}

$data | Export-Excel -Path C:\outputFile.xlsx
```